# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get the result from my database table `tbl_newpage` but it throws error. I don't know why it throws error

The following line

```
   $page = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['page']);

   $result=array();

   if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from tbl_newpage where name=?")){

     $stmt->bind_param("s", $page);

     $stmt->execute();

     $result = $stmt->get_result();

     while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

       $result[] = array($row); //This is where the error appears 
                echo "hello ";print_r($row);die();

     }

     $objSmarty->assign("result", $result);
   }
```

Throws error

Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in `/var/www/html/examplesite/phpfile.php` on line 22

Comment: add comment in the code on the error line

Comment: Change `$result[]` array to some other name something like `$data` because `$result` array store value of `get_result()`

Comment: @Saty Thank you very much

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the same variable `$result` for both the result of `$stmt->get_result()` and also the array of values that you're fetching. So on the second iteration of the loop, when it does

```
$row = $result->fetch_array()
```

`$result` no longer contains the `mysqli` result, it contains the array, and you can't call `fetch_array()` on an array. Use different variable names for them.

```
$output = array();
while ($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
    $output[] = $row;
}
$objSmarty->assign("result", $output);
```

Also, `$row` is already an array, you probably don't want to nest it in another array before pushing it onto the `$output` array.

Comment: it's a very nice explanation but the while loop is missing closing )

Answer (score 3):

Try by changing final `result` as `finalResult`

```
 $page = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_GET['page']);

 $finalResult=array();

 if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("select * from tbl_newpage where name=?")){

 $stmt->bind_param("s", $page);

 $stmt->execute();

 $result = $stmt->get_result();

 while($row = $result->fetch_array()){

   $finalResult[] = array($row);
            echo "hello ";print_r($row);die();

 }

 $objSmarty->assign("result", $finalResult);
 }
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the problem